# How can I pass a stored procedure parameter into a cursor in snowflake?

Tags: sql, stored-procedures, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I am currently trying to pass a parameter into a stored procedure and use this parameter when creating a cursor unsuccessfully. Here is a simplified snippet of the code I currently have for creating the stored procedure:

```
     CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE PROC_MODEL_CREATE_TABLE_PROFILE(TABLE2PROFILE string)
        RETURNS TABLE()
        LANGUAGE SQL
        AS
        $$
        
       
        
        declare
        
            sql string;
            final_sql string;
            c1 cursor for (
            
        
        SELECT
    
        TABLE_NAME as TABLENAME
        from TABLE_OF_TABLES
        WHERE tablename LIKE ANY (' ||:TABLE2PROFILE|| ')
        ORDER BY TABLENAME;
            res resultset;
        begin
        
          final_sql := '';
          
          for record in c1 do
    sql := 'SELECT COUNT(*) AS Number_Of_Rows'
    FROM '||record.tablename||';

    final_sql := final_sql || sql;
        
  end for;
  
   final_sql := 'create or replace table data_profiles_LATEST as (' || final_sql || ')';

  res := (execute immediate :final_sql);
return table(res);
```

I then call the stored procedure using:

```
CALL PROC_MODEL_CREATE_TABLE_PROFILE('TABLE_OF_INTEREST');
```

However, when this stored procedure is run, it just runs the string ' ||:TABLE2PROFILE|| ' without passing the parameter. I can hard code 'TABLE2PROFILE' with 'TABLE_OF_INTEREST' it works fine. How can I pass a parameter into the stored procedure and use it in the cursor?

Comment: Its difficult to comprehend what you are trying to do, but one example of how to pass parameters to SQL can be - ```execute immediate 'select count(*) from '||:table_name;```  Notice the placement of quotes.

Comment: The issue is that you've encapsulated the variable reference in the string.  Instead of LIKE ANY ' ||:TABLE2PROFILE|| '  you should use LIKE ANY (:TABLE2PROFILE);  ... however, the approach @pankaj listed above is a lot cleaner way of executing as a dynamic SQL statement.  I think you've got other issues in that stored proc.  What is it you're trying to accomplish?  There are likely better ways to accomplish it ...

Comment: The original code was based off this solution in which a long sql script is generated and then ran. (stackoverflow.com/questions/71684411/…). I was just attempting to make it dynamic to accept a parameter for the table to profile. Also, I try the recommended syntax and get the error "Bind variable :TABLE2PROFILE not set."  Also, using @pankaj's solution, it appears to only run the statement without passing the parameter when I review the SQL logs.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are syntactical issue in the code shared.
As I understand you want to pass a multi-valued string, select based on that and then do further operations.

Please refer sample code below that shows same.

Notice how to use multi-values variable for `LIKE ANY`.

Notice how to use parameter in cursor variable.
Refer [this](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/developer-guide/snowflake-scripting/cursors.html#declaring-a-cursor) for details on passing parameter to cursor variables.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE PROC_MODEL_CREATE_TABLE_PROFILE(TABLE2PROFILE string)
        RETURNS string
LANGUAGE SQL
AS
        $$
        declare
            sql string;
            final_sql string;
            c1 cursor for
SELECT *
from test_tab
where name like ANY (select value from table(split_to_table(?,',')));

        begin
  open c1 using (:TABLE2PROFILE);
          final_sql := '';
          for record in c1 do
    sql := 'SELECT  '
||record.name||';';
    final_sql := final_sql || sql;
  end for;
return final_sql;
end;
$$;
```

Procedure execution -

```
call PROC_MODEL_CREATE_TABLE_PROFILE('%oh%,%ar%');
```

| PROC_MODEL_CREATE_TABLE_PROFILE |
| --- |
| SELECT John;SELECT Mark;SELECT Gary; |

Source table used in procedure -

```
select * from test_tab limit 1;
```

| ID | NAME | CREATED |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | John | 14/03/2022 |

Comment: Thank you for making sense of the code, as I struggled to simplify the example to focus on the most troublesome aspect. They key for this was replacing the variable with the ? then using the command 'open c1 using (:TABLE2PROFILE);' and then having the for loop afterwards. I found references to this in the Snowflake documentation but could not find any code examples.